# TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm using Cucumber with Watir Web-driver and Chrome browser.
When I execute my tests, sometimes there is an error like this:

> "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(., 'Joao Moreira')] because of the following error:
>   TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>     (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)"

I tried to get an answer trough Google but with no success.

Comment: same here: definitely sporadic, noticed it soon after upgrading to selenium 2.45

Comment: I have had this while running 2.44, and with Chromedriver 2.14 and 2.15.

My feeling is that it happened when Chrome upgraded to 43

Comment: Out of interest, is there a pattern on what the browser is doing when this occurs?

Comment: In my case it is switching between frame windows

Comment: Just to add data points: Selenium 2.46 and Chrome 44 and it is sporadic but often enough.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is this issue here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8600

And it is fixed as of Selenium 2.46.0. I haven't seen the error since moving.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line to handle the exception thrown. Seems like the error halts the test. This has nothing to do with the locator, or iframe.Try to wrap your method in rescue clause:

```
begin
 {your method}
rescue
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError
end
```